# How to route based on current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

If `current_user` is present, I would like to ask if `current_user.client_or_customer == "client"`. If so, I would like to show the `client_dashboard.html.erb` view, elsif `current_user.client_or_customer == "customer"` I would like to show the `customer_dashboard.html.erb`

Is there a way to check in the routes if a param is present, or how to initialize the `current_user`?

Please excuse the limited knowledge of rails.

Comment: If you want to check if a parameter `foo` is present, just call `params[:foo]`. How to initialize `current_user` depends on how you (or the gem you're using) defined the `current_user` method.

Comment: I actually have tried that. I put a binding.pry in the routes and called `params` in the console. This was the error message it threw: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f881919f548>`

Comment: You shouldn't be actually checking params or reading the current user in routes. You should do this in a controller.

Comment: Are you using devise?

Comment: I am using devise. So, I should check if the params are in the controller and build the logic there?

Comment: Yup, and I am assuming you created a `#client_or_customer` method already

Comment: I am. Great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be actually checking params or reading the current user in routes. You should do this in a controller.

```
def index
  if current_user && current_user.client_or_customer == "client"
    render 'client_dashboard'
  elsif current_user && current_user.client_or_customer == "customer"
    render 'customer_dashboard'
  else
    render 'guest'
  end
end
```